# Sorting Of a String using selection sort containg numbers also

Tags: arrays, string, sorting

the task is to implement the sorting machine which does sorting by using Selection sort algorithm in which the smallest words and numbers are placed at the head of the array. In first pass, the machine applies the Selection sort to words and in second pass it applies to numbers, so on and so forth until all the text is processed.also code is capable to give instataneous answers also i.e pass no is enterd by user it must show the o/p at that pass.. I actually mean by that was code must be able to accept the pass no: means if I enter 3 then it must show output of 3rd pass in selection sort.not the completely sorted array.

Input:
    3 // pass no of which result is desired

```
Story 31 of 45 TOM 11 and 90
```

Output:

```
and 11 of 45 tom 31 story 90
```

Comment: The question is unclear, please write full sentences, and include samples

Comment: Why is `tom` before `story` and `45` before `31`? It looks like you want to have a word, then a number, then a word, then a number, etc., and have the words sorted and also the numbers sorted - is this correct? What have you tried? Which language are you trying to do this in?

Comment: yes.. exctly and the words must be sorted im trying this in c

Comment: Why C? Why not C++? Is using C part of the challenge? If so, then you should add that to the question I guess.

Comment: no we can do it any language there is no such restrictions..

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your problem correctly.
I don't get what you mean with: "also code is capable to give instataneous ans also ie pass no is enterd bu user it must show the o/p at that pass.. "

An implementation in C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


/* Generic in place selection-sort
 * NOTE: T must be comparable with '<' 
 */
template<typename T>
void selectionSort(vector<T> &array){
    //For each 'position' we look for the smallest element in the remainder of the array.
    for(int position = 0; position < array.size(); ++position){

        //'selected' keeps track of where the minimum element is.
        int selected = position;

        for(int checkPosition = (position+1); checkPosition < array.size(); ++checkPosition){
            if(array[checkPosition] < array[selected]){
                //if we found a smaller element, then select it.
                selected = checkPosition;
            }
        }

        //swap the selected element to the currentPosition
        T temp = array[position];
        array[position] = array[selected];
        array[selected] = temp;
    }
}




int main(){
    vector<string> strings;
    vector<int> numbers;

    //read input
    string str;
    int num;
    while(cin >> str){
        //convert string to lower case.
        transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::tolower);
        cin >> num;
        strings.push_back(str);
        numbers.push_back(num);
    }

    //sort
    selectionSort(strings);
    selectionSort(numbers);

    //print output
    for(int curr=0; curr < strings.size(); ++curr){
        cout << strings[curr] << " " << numbers[curr] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I have to say I don't get the output how you wrote it.

Input:

```
Story 31 of 45 TOM 11 and 90
```

Output:

```
and 11 of 31 story 45 tom 90
```

Anyway, I hope that even if this is not *exactly* what you asked for it gives you some idea on how to solve your problem.

Comment: I actually mean by that was code must be able to accept the pass no: means if i enter 3 then it must show output of 3 pass in selection sort.not the complety sorted array..

Comment: @BhaveshBarskar Ok. And my solution does not help you enoguh to figure out how to that? I mean I can add that if you want. But have you tried taking this solution and modifying it a bit? It should be quite si ple to add that...